# Results from transformation with Feature Agglomeration

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, unsupervised-learning

I am using the transform function from the feature agglomeration object from scikit-learn on a matrix with data. After running the transform function, on the resulting matrix (X_reduced in the code), is the first element the result of the agglomeration of cluster 0, the second element for cluster 1, and so on? Or is it random?

```py
from sklearn import Cluster
agglo = cluster.FeatureAgglomeration(n_clusters=100)
agglo.fit(X_train_prepared)
X_reduced = agglo.transform(X_train_prepared)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relative to labeling you get from `agglo.labels_` -- yes, first column of resulting matrix is cluster zero.

I.e. the following holds:

```
from sklearn import cluster
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris, make_blobs
import pandas as pd
agglo = cluster.FeatureAgglomeration(n_clusters=95)
X,y = make_blobs(n_features=100)
agglo.fit(X)
X_reduced = agglo.transform(X)
# first column in reduced is the mean of all columns that lie in the first cluster
>>> all(X_reduced[:,0] == X[:,(agglo.labels_ == 0).nonzero()[0]].mean(axis=1))
True
```